# How to call a method for every instace of a class in android

Tags: java, class, methods

I would like to call a method for every instance of one of my classes, but have no clue how to go about doing that.

```
public class demostration{
    public void m(){

    }
}
demonstration d = new demonstration();
demonstration p = new demonstration();
```

How can I call the method m so that all instances of demonstration run that method? I.e. so it has the same effect as writing

```
d.m();
p.m();
```

Comment: you are writing it wrong, it's d.m() and p.m() don't forget parenthesis/brackets it's a method not a field !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you create a new instance, put it into some type of [mutable array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). When you want to call the method m of each instance, simply [loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) through the array of instances, calling m on each instance.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others are saying, putting the instances into an `ArrayList` makes the most sense.  You could try this:

```
 demonstration a = new demonstration();
 demonstration b = new demonstration();
 demonstration c = new demonstration();

 ArrayList<demonstration> demos = new ArrayList<demonstration>();
 demos.add(a); 
 demos.add(b);
 demos.add(c);

 for(Demonstration d : demos) {

    d.m();

 }
```

Also, just a nitpicky thing from my point of view: It's good Java-style syntax to start class names with a capital letter, so Demonstrations` might be a better name.  Just my opinion :D